# Contents of Docker images

Tags: docker

What exaxtly a Docker image may contain? As it is mantioned that image can have all possible dependecies require for a microservice, so how do an image intract with databases?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/

Answer (score 0):

A docker **image** just contains the software and its dependencies. Then you use that image to create one or multiple **containers** using that image. When creating the container you can inject configuration and mount up external persistent storage if needed.

Think of running containers as virtual machines with their own ip addresses except that the container itself do not run an actual OS. The processes will actually run on the host OS, but they are completely isolated by the kernel.

I docker image mainly contains files. Often they contain file structure from an an OS. For example ubuntu, centos, alpine linux etc.. These files are only there to support the application and provide the most common tools.

Comment: It really helps , so is correct that one image always denotes a mircoservice in cloud?

Comment: Pretty much yes. You build as small image as you can that can run a single process. Then you can run multiple instances to scale you system up. You can of course treat a container as a virtual machine running lots of stuff, but that makes it hard to scale up.

Comment: Added more to the answer to clarify.